# In WPF, is there a way to bind to sibling properties?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml

I have a series of `TextBlock` and `TextBox` controls.  Is there a way to apply a `Style` to the `TextBlock`s such that they can databind to the control immediately after them?

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
<Resources..>
    <Style x:Key="BindToFollowingTextBoxSibling">
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FollowingSibling}, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" />
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FollowingSibling}, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource TextToBrushConverter}}" />
        ... More properties and converters.
    </Style>
</Resources>

...

<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource BindToFollowingTextBoxSibling}"/>
<TextBox/>

<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource BindToFollowingTextBoxSibling}"/>
<TextBox/>
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource BindToPreviousTextBoxSibling}"/>
```

Is something like this even possible?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think the best thing to do in this case is bind by ElementName:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=textBox1, Path=Text}" />
<TextBox x:Name="textBox1">this is the textBox's 1 text</TextBox>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=textBox2, Path=Text}" />
<TextBox x:Name="textBox2">this is the textBox's 2 text</TextBox>
```

It will achieve something similar. Does this work for you?

Comment: That's kind of what I'm likely going to do.  The problem is that there are several properties and converters that I'm looking at binding, so it gets to be a lot of copy and past to do this for every property.  I'm thinking I might bind by ElementName to the TextBlock's Tag and then use RelativeSource Self to get the properties that I need.

Comment: I ended up just creating a user-control that handled the cases that I needed.  It was just easier.

Comment: Haha cool man, my solution wasn't an optimal approach to your problem, glad you solved it =)

Answer (score 31):

I know this is an old thread, but I've **found a solution to this problem**.  I was able to use 
Aland Li's suggestion, found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/2e2ff0d0-7138-4741-a121-d92ea2b4e698/).  Its not quite as generic as it is in CSS, but if you know the parent element type, this works nicely **even in a Style**.

Here's an example of how I used it.  I have a TextBox control that lights up with a "highlight color" when it has focus.  Additionally, I wanted its associated Label control to also light up when the TextBox had focus.  So I wrote a Trigger for the Label control that made it light up in a similar way that the TextBox control did.  This Trigger is triggered by a custom attached property called IsFocusedByProxy.  Then I needed to bind the Label's IsFocusedByProxy to the TextBox's IsFocused.  So I used this technique:

```
<Grid x:Name="MaxGrid">
    <Label  x:Name="MaxLabel"
            Content="Max:"  
            c5:TagHelper.IsFocusedByProxy="{Binding 
                                  Path=Children[1].IsFocused,
                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}}" 
       />
     <c5:TextBoxC5Mediator x:Name="MaxTextBox"                          
                           DataContext="{Binding ConfigVm.Max_mediator}" />
</Grid>
```

At this point you may be thinking that its not any better than than just using ElementName in the Binding.  **But the difference is that now I can move this binding into a Style for reusability:**

```
<Setter Property="C5_Behaviors:TagHelper.IsFocusedByProxy"
        Value="{Binding Path=Children[1].IsFocused,
                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}}" />
```

And now I can when I have a View full of these occurances, like this (I have setup the necessary Styles to be applied implicitly, so that's why there's no markup shown that sets the Styles):

```
<Grid x:Name="MaxGrid">
    <Label  x:Name="MaxLabel"
            Content="Max:"  />
    <c5:TextBoxC5Mediator x:Name="MaxTextBox"                          
                          DataContext="{Binding ConfigVm.Max_mediator}" />
 </Grid> 
 <Grid x:Name="MinGrid">
     <Label  x:Name="MinLabel"
             Content="Min:" />
     <c5:TextBoxC5Mediator x:Name="MinTextBox"                          
                           DataContext="{Binding ConfigVm.Min_mediator}" />
</Grid>
<Grid x:Name="StepFactorGrid">
    <Label  x:Name="StepFactorLabel"
            Content="Step Factor:" />
    <c5:TextBoxC5Mediator x:Name="StepFactorTextBox"                          
                          DataContext="{Binding ConfigVm.StepFactor_mediator}" />
</Grid>
<!-- ... and lots more ... -->
```

**Which gives me these results**:

Before any TextBoxes have focus:

[image: Before any TextBoxes have focus]

With different TextBoxes receiving focus:

[image: after focus 1]

[image: after focus 2]

Comment: +1 for `{Binding Path=Children[1].IsFocused, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}}`.

Comment: So I am assuming the "1" in Path=Children[1]... is the index? This did work for me, but wanted to clarify the meaning of the number value.

Comment: @EdwardM Correct, the `1` in `Path=Children[1]` is an index (zero-based index of course). So you could adjust that number if your structure was different.  Cheers.