# WPF - Binding to control using relative path Self.Sibling.Child

Tags: wpf

Below is the XAML i currently have. I want to emulate a tree by having a toggle button and a listview will bind it's visibility to the toggle buttons chcked state. Problem is, I need to bind to a child of a sibling. Is this even possible?

this code doesn't work becuase the toggle isn't an ancestor.

```
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <ToggleButton Name="tglBtn">+</ToggleButton>
                            <TextBlock>test</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                    <ListView Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ToggleButton}}, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}}">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Thread"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding thread_name}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Created"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding thread_created}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Modified" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding last_modified}" />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>

        </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>


    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ElementName Binding to access the ToggleButton

Comment: I was going to use elementname but I thought it would bind to all toggles with the same name but i just tried it and it works just fine.

Comment: Yeah, I know we might think that way since we used it inside a DataTemplate :) But consider a regular UserControl and we put ElementName Binding into it with out a second thought. But see that same usercontrol can get instantiated many times in the app. So each DataTemplate instance has its own scope to cover that ( I guess !)

Comment: As long as it works, i could careless at this point @Jobi! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've **found a solution** to this problem that is reusable in Styles (it does not require using the ElementName).  I've written up the full answer, with examples and screenshots [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16741102/718325).