# How do I get a control's style to point to its sibling control when using a trigger?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

Since I can't change a control's cursor through a trigger if it's disabled, I created a separate transparent border with a no cursor to show up on top of the control if ever the former is disabled.

I wanted to shorten my code so I created a custom border style defining everything I need and wanted to apply it to every cancel border needed BUT the problem is that it relies on a data trigger pointing to the name of the control disabled for it to show up, so my problem now is what's the best way I could tell the style to "check the sibling control within the grid and check if it's enabled/disabled".

What I've tried so far is to simply create multiple data triggers pointing to the names of the control but find it to be a bit messy. Also, I wanted this to be used for the entire app so it'd be nice if I could simply create a border and apply the style without needing to go to the actual style and creating another trigger.

Another solution I have in mind is to register all necessary controls to an IsEnabled_Changed event and do the sibling search from there and set the latter's visibility depending on the former's IsEnabled status.

Here's the example of the style:

```
<Style x:Key="CancelBorder_Style" TargetType="Border">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="{DynamicResource GlobalCornerRadius}"/>
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="No"/>
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MiddleNameTB,Path=IsEnabled}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Here's the example of the border and its sibling:

```
<Grid Style="{DynamicResource RegCtrlGrid_Style}" >
    <TextBox x:Name="MiddleNameTB" />
    <Border Style="{DynamicResource CancelBorder_Style}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I realized this would be chaos since all of them use the same style, maybe I could create the cancel border instead on my resource, set x:Shared="False" and create new instances of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a couple of things since I realized that if they shared the same styles then a trigger that wasn't meant for them can be used.

First of all I created the Border on my resource instead:

```
<Border x:Key="CancelBorder" x:Shared="False">
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border" >
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="{DynamicResource GlobalCornerRadius}"/>
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="No"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Children[0].IsEnabled,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>
```

Then applied it on my ui:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2" Style="{DynamicResource RegCtrlGrid_Style}">
    <TextBox x:Name="MiddleNameTB"/>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="CancelBorder"/>
</Grid>
```

The trick was using:

`{Binding Path=Children[0].IsEnabled,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}}`

Wherein the [0] is based on the children's index under the parent

Big thanks to Jason Frank for his answer on ([In WPF, is there a way to bind to sibling properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870931/in-wpf-is-there-a-way-to-bind-to-sibling-properties/16741102))